# converting css into responsive

Tags: css

I'm using css style sheet.every thing is fine here is my code snippets

```
   .stickytooltip {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #818181; /*shadow for CSS3 capable browsers.*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #818181;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #818181;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    border: 5px solid black; /*Border around tooltip*/
    background: white;
    z-index: 3000;
}


    .map {
    outline:solid;
    }
   .stickytooltip .stickystatus{ /*Style for footer bar within tooltip*/
   background:black;
   color:white;
   padding-top:5px;
   text-align:center;
   font:bold 11px Arial;
   }
```

but i need converting into resposive css how it's ????? please help

Comment: That's a very broad question. What exactly do you want /converting/ into responsive?

Comment: Vendor prefixes should come *before* standard properties. Also, [`box-shadow` (the standard property name) has been supported by modern browsers for quite some time now](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow).

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how it should be responsive / show a working version?

Comment: just like a bootstap

Answer (score 1):

To make CSS responsive, you need to use Media Queries.
You can find more informations here : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Hope it will help.